# mariadb 5.5.36 with innodb plugin

Tags: innodb, mariadb

I installed `mariadb 5.5.36` on a `win32` system. Everything runs fine except innodb requests are 2 x slower than an identical MySQL installation. So I want to switch back to original innodb plugin to test the performance with it.

In `my.ini` I put under [mysqld] the following:

```
ignore_builtin_innodb
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb.dll
```

The plugin is located in `BASEDIR/lib/plugin`.

But when I start the service I get the following in the error log:

```
140315 18:03:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

If I comment both lines out then everything runs fine.

Even when i try to run a plain mariadb data dir (without the log files ...) the error occurs.

Is there someone who have a hint for me?